# Jest - ReferenceError: spyOn is not defined

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, ts-jest

I am trying to mock a return value from a subscription's in my angular unit test. Found tons of example, but all are using `spyOn` in combination with  `.and.returnValue(of())`.
For `spyOn` i am getting

> ReferenceError: spyOn is not defined

So changed it to `jest.spyOn` but now I am getting the error:

> Property 'and' does not exist on type 'SpyInstance<void, [request: ValidationRequest]>'

my code is:

`jest.spyOn(validationFacade, 'validateOrder').and.returnValue(of(validationResponseMock).pipe(delay(1)));`

Please help how to replace `.and.returnValue(of())`!

Thanks in advance for you help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per my understanding you are writing in Angular with Jest. If I am right, Please try this way.
It worked for me:

```js
jest.spyOn(validationFacade, 'validateOrder').mockReturnValue(of(validationResponseMock));
```

Answer (score 2):

I used jest.spyOn and mockReset()

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(component.dialogRef, 'close').mockReset();
```